# Native Query Not Map Count(*) variable

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, nativequery

i am working on Jpa Native query,

I want all my all send with it count but this my query

```
select id,status,COUNT(*) as count from tb_abc where sender_id=?1 group by status
```

But problem is when i will run it on Mysql then it will run fine but when i will run using java code i.e native query then then count is return null or 0..

This my class which i have map from query

This Native Query

@Repository
public class PatientAppointmentNativeDao {

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<TableAbc> get(Long senderId) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<TableAbc> resultData = (List<TableAbc>) em
            .createNativeQuery(
                    "select *,COUNT(*) as count from tb_abc where sender_id=?1 group by status",
                    com.abc.TableAbc.class)
            .setParameter(1, senderId)
            .getResultList();

    return resultData;
}
```

}

and TableABC class is as:

public class PatientAppointment {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;



@ManyToOne
private Sender sender;

private Integer status;


@Transient
private int countTotal;

public int getCountTotal() {
    return countTotal;
}

public void setCountTotal(int countTotal) {
    this.countTotal = countTotal;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}




public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

Please help me ...

Comment: For native query use '@Transactional` annotation

Comment: No effect using @Transactional again get 0 value as count

Comment: Try `?` instead of `?1`. That is almost the only change w.r.t. your mysql manual test. Though I had my doubt on `as count` reusing a function name.

Comment: Unrelated but: your count will give you not the results you think it will because your `group by` usage is wrong (and every other DBMS would simply reject that query). See e.g. here for a explanation: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: But when i will try it on Mysql interface then it will work fine